# SSIS Concatenating Two Functions in Derived column

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I am concatenating but it is showing error

```
UPPER(SUBSTRING( [a],1,1)) + FINDSTRING( [a]," ",1)
```

The [a] value looks like:

```
snoffy ab
```

Comment: Elaborate the description to understand it clearly.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions below??

Answer (score 1):

[FINDSTRING()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/findstring-ssis-expression) Function will return a `DT_I4` value which cannot be concateneted with a string, just cast it:

```
UPPER(SUBSTRING([a],1,1)) + (DT_WSTR,10)FINDSTRING([a]," ",1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the 1st list from your array value.

- [Array of string into a variable in SSIS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/38783726-ced5-4452-a68c-99cf11e6a6e3/array-of-string-into-a-variable-in-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices)